# Можно ли написать драйвер для NCR Caash Dispenser, используя его протокол на языке программирования C#?

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь реализовать драйвер для диспенсера NСR, используя его протокол. Можно ли сделать это? Или есть готовый драйвер с открытым исходным кодом.

Comment: Драйвер устройства под CLR написать нельзя, потому что CLR не может работать режиме ядра операционной системы.

Comment: Невозможно написать программу по протоколу для отправка команды на устройства(ncr cash dispenser) ?